What does the law say if someone locks their bicycle to mine?
Say I park my bicycle, lock it, and then a few hours later when I come back I find someone has locked their bicycle to mine.
What does the law say:

Do they commit a crime by removing my ability to retrieve my bike?
Do I commit a crime if I destroy the lock and retrieve my bike? What if, by destroying the lock, I also leave their bike vulnerable to theft (and it is indeed stolen)?

No particular jurisdiction in mind.
Related: Someone else's lock on my bike which doesn't deal with the legal aspects of the issue.

This is widely discussed in forums and the answer seems to be "sorry you're out of luck". Cycling UK, Reddit. You can read up on the defense of necessity but that only applies if people or property are actively in danger, not just inconvenienced. In theory you could call the police, but good luck with that.
